# Colocating HBase and MapReduce processes in the same cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Why is colocating HBase and MapReduce processes in the same cluster typically not recommended?

Comment: Can you give us a reference for this statement? Where do you have it from?

Comment: If you have performance issues on your hbase cluster, either you can expand your cluster or make a new less performant mapreduce cluster for batch jobs. This depends on your read/write ratio, mapreduce usage pattern, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue is that analytics IO, especially the read operations, can run disks at full bandwidth. HDFS, which needs to share that bandwidth, can suffer; your SLAs on responsiveness are in trouble.

What you can do is have a single HDFS cluster, split between analytics and HBase

1. Don't run YARN Nodemanagers on one rack; dedicate it to HBase
2. Do run RMs everywhere, but use YARN labels to distinguish the hbase nodes from ones which analytics workloads can use; attach labels to queues so that most work doesn't run on the HBase nodes.

The second option is what we do when using Apache Slider (incubating) to deploy HBase in a YARN cluster. You label things so that the HBase nodes get exclusive use of those machines. Even there, remote network IO can still end up asking for data off those servers, but the YARN placement schedulers always try to avoid scheduling work that way, so it's a lot less.